# PHP PDO how to hash password upon registration and then 'unhash' during login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am finishing up an application. I have fairly heavy validation going on within the scripting but I want to step it up by hashing the password when it is sent to the database that way it does not go in as plain text. I have tried several methods but found no luck with it as of yet.

Here is the code (Hosted on GitHub's Gist program):

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5c4f6ab9443d9ce887266b79bc36a1a

As you can see in the password validation portion of the script, I have it where if the password passes all other validation then it get's hashed. But it doesn't seem to be working when I check my database. That is issue #1. On top of that I couldn't find any methods that would unhash the password and also how to implement an 'unhashing' technique in my login.php file that I included in the link above. I appreciate any help or tips you guys may offer. Thanks so much!

Comment: You should create [a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just post a link to github gist.

Comment: I apologize, I felt that seeing the whole script would help people get a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve... my bad.

Comment: Try to take the part which illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hashes are not meant to be "unhashed"; hash functions are one way functions. The purpose of hashes is to compare them to another hash. In the case of `password_hash()`, it's complementary function is `password_verify()`. Read up on [cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) on Wikipedia.

Comment: PS.: I forgot to mention that it's also important to get an understanding of what a salt is, in the context of hashing, as this will make it clear why simply comparing hashed passwords from `password_hash()`, does not work: `password_hash()` creates a unique salt for each password (which is prepended to its result) and `password_verify()` uses this salt again to compare the hashes. I might write a more elaborate answer for you later on today.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I will accept your answer once you post it. I appreciate the information you just gave me! Thanks!

Comment: Here's a simile I find useful: you can create a 160-bit SHA1 hash of any string; for instance, a movie ripped from a blue-ray disc. Imagine if you could "unhash" it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General information on (cryptographic) hashing

Hashing is often confused with encrypting, but they're different and have different use-cases:

[Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) is meant for encoding something such that it can be deciphered again (with the right key), making it a two-way process.

[(Cryptographic) hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), on the other hand, is a *one-way* process to encode something that is explicitly *not* meant to be decipherable. Furthermore, a hashing function is deterministic, meaning that given the same message, it will always produce the same digest.<sup>1</sup>

**So, here is why cryptographic hashing is used to encode passwords:**
For hopefully obvious security reasons, you don't want anyone to be able to decipher the hashed password (not some adversary who was able to compromise your database and not even you, the web master, since that would allow you to compromise a user's account somewhere else, if they use the same password over there), but you *do* want to be able to verify that the password entered by the user matches the password they signed up with.

Since, as mentioned before, a hashing function is deterministic, we can achieve this by comparing the hash produced at an authentication process (such as logging in) and the hash produced at the sign-up process.

*"But wait...," I hear you think, "in your comment you told me I would not be able to simply compare them".*

If the message given to a bare hashing function is the same, you *can* and that's the problem with the deterministic aspect of hashing functions, in the context of password hashing: they produce the same output.

This means that if Alice, Bob and Charlie use the same password, they all produce the same digests:

```
 id | username | pwdhash 
----+----------+---------
 17 | Alice    | 9Wdm...
 48 | Bob      | 9Wdm...
 57 | Charlie  | 9Wdm...
```

This poses two prominent security risks:

1. if you know Alice's password, you know the others' as well;
2. an adversary could, knowing the hashing function you use, theoretically generate, what is called, a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)<sup>2</sup> and compare its hashes with your hashes (if your database was compromised), to infer the actual passwords that match those in the rainbow table.

So, to mitigate these risks it is considered mandatory practice to add, what is called, a salt to the message (the password), before hashing it. A salt is meant to be unique enough to guarantee that two identical passwords produce completely different digests when fed to the same hashing function.

Pseudo example:

```
// produces same digests:
hash( 'password' ) -> bhZPmushb...
hash( 'password' ) -> bhZPmushb...

// produces unique digests:
        salt       message
hash( 'SeNib6' . 'password' ) -> qDHkfTW9m...
hash( '9pBq7y' . 'password' ) -> XH26YVUnA...
```

And this, by default, is what `password_hash()` automatically does for you, under the hood.<sup>3</sup> It then prepends the used salt to the digest, along with information about the actual algorithm that was used and the cost.<sup>4</sup> `password_verify()` will then use this additional information and the used salt to generate the same digest again, if the provided password matches the earlier hashed password.

It's therefore essential that the complete output of `password_hash()` is stored so that it can be fed into `password_verify()` as its second argument.

### So, what does all this mean for your case?

Since `password_hash()` automatically adds a salt and therefore generates two different digests for identical passwords, you can't simply compare `password_hash()`'s output. This also means you can't (easily; I wouldn't be surprised if there was *some* way to make it work) compare password hashes at the database level, like you intended, with `password = :password`; you will have to compare the hashes in PHP, which means that you will have to fetch the user's record first and then verify the password hashes:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE username = :username";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array('username' => $_POST["userName"]));

// I believe PDOStatement::rowCount() doesn't work with MySQL for SELECT statements
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = count($rows);
if($count > 1) { // this might be redundant in your setup
  // this is not supposed to happen, usernames should be unique
  // log or alert developer
}
else if($count == 1) {
  $row = $rows[0];
  if(password_verify($_POST["userPass"], $row['password')) {
    // don't store $_POST["userName"] in $_SESSION["username"], but use the database value
    $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
    header("Location: user-homepage.php");
    // it's good practice to exit after a redirect, unless other code still needs to be executed
    exit();
  }
}

$message = '<label>Invalid Credentials</label>';
```

---

<sup>1) The output of a hashing function is often called the digest or simply the hash.

2) A rainbow table is a database generated by giving the target hashing function a large list of probable passwords, i.e. generating, by brute force, a long list of digests to compare to a compromised set of digests. This is usually a rather time-intensive operation.

3) I'm not actually sure whether `password_hash()` prepends or appends the salt to the password to generate the digest.

4) See the documentation for more information about the [format of the output](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) (explained in the FAQ about password hashing) [algorithms](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-description) (explained in `password_hash()`) and [cost](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) (explained in `crypt()`).</sup>